# Expected value and autocorrelation

Tags: autocorrelation, self-study

I have a wide sense stationary stochastic process ${{X_t;t\in \Re}}$ with mean 0 and autocorrelation function $R_x(\tau)=1-\frac{1}{4}|\tau|$ for $|\tau|=0,1,2,3;$ and zero anywhere else. I'm supposed to calculate the linear minimal mean square estimator (LMMSE) of $Z=\frac{1}{2}(X_t+X_{t-1})$ based on $(X_{t-2},X_{t-3})$, for which i need $E(ZX_{t-2})$ and $E(ZX_{t-3})$.

The first one ends up as $E(ZX_{t-2})=\frac{1}{2}(R_X(2)+R_X(1))$, never mind the second one.

I fail to understand how this calculation works. How can $E(ZX_{t-2})$ end up as $\frac{1}{2}(R_X(2)+R_X(1))$. On one hand, $t=2$ and $t=1$ could simply be inserted into $Z=\frac{1}{2}(X_t+X_{t-1})$, but how does this relate to the expected value of $ZX_{t-2}$? What's the calculation in between? What's the reasoning?

Comment: What is the difference, if any, between the $R$ that appears in $t\in R$ and the $R$ that occurs in $R_x(\tau)$?  If the first $R$ should be $\mathbb R$ a.k.a. the real line, then note that you only know the value of $R_x(\tau)$ for integer values of $\tau$.  What about something like $R_x(1.5)$? What is its value?

Comment: There are other notational problems.  I wonder what textbook these folks get that put a continuous-time argument down at the subscript?....... Oh.  $t$ is not continuous time, but is discrete time.  I wish they would use $n$.

Comment: You still don't get it. If $t$ is allowed to be _any_ real number (as evidenced by your statement that $t \in \mathcal R$, then $R_x(\tau)$ needs to be specified for **every real number** $\tau$, not just for $|\tau| = 0,1,2,3$.  And before you yammer that you did say that $R_x(\tau)$ is given to be $0$ everywhere other than $0, \pm 1, \pm 2, \pm 3$, let me tell you that the $R_x(\tau)$ that you state is **not** a valid autocorrelation function.  It would also help if _you_ include a formal definition of $R_x(\tau)$ _in general_ for an arbitrary WSS process.  -1 pending suitable corrections.

Comment: Robert and Dilip, sorry, but you two have absolutely nothing of an answer to my solution. How about you take the issues that you have with my examinator. I don’t care about your issues with his notations!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By defition, the autocorrelation function at lag $\tau$ is
$$R_X(\tau) = \mathbb{E}(X_t X_{t-\tau})$$
Now the expected value of $ZX_{t-2}$ is
$$\mathbb{E}(ZX_{t-2}) = \mathbb{E} \left(\frac{1}{2} (X_t + X_{t-1}) X_{t-2} \right)$$
$$ = \frac{1}{2} \bigg(\mathbb{E}(X_t X_{t-1}) + \mathbb{E}(X_t X_{t-2})\bigg)$$
$$ = \frac{1}{2} \bigg(R_X(\tau = 1) + R_X(\tau = 2)\bigg)$$

Comment: Maybe clearer: $\mathbb{E}(\frac{1}{2}(X_t+X_{t-1})X_{t-2})) = \frac{1}{2}(\mathbb{E}(X_tX_{t-2}) + \mathbb{E}(X_{t-1}X_{t-2})) = \frac{1}{2}(\mathbb{E}(X_tX_{t-2}) + \mathbb{E}(X_{t}X_{t-1}))$

Comment: Thanks you guys, that was helpful. More than I could say for the two dudes that were having issues about notations.